# Modify .bst to introduce a period instead of a comma after journal name

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I am writing for a biology journal that has its own citation style. I have been able to manipulate `apalike.bst` through trial and error to make most of the style changes but I can't figure out how to put a period after the journal name instead of a comma. For example, instead of

> Goshima, G., Wollman, R., Goodwin, S. S., Zhang, N., Scholey, J. M., Vale, R. D., and Stuurman, N. (2007). Genes required for mitotic spindle assembly in Drosophila S2 cells. Science, 316(5823). 417–421.

I'd like a period after "Science" as follows:

> Goshima, G., Wollman, R., Goodwin, S. S., Zhang, N., Scholey, J. M., Vale, R. D., and Stuurman, N. (2007). Genes required for mitotic spindle assembly in Drosophila S2 cells. Science. 316(5823). 417–421.

Any help?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  i think you might want to fix the title to ask what you describe in the text.

Comment: Could yoiu consider using `biblatex-apa`?

Comment: I figured it out by trying to replace every ```", "``` in the .bst file. If anyone has the same problem, try editing ```FUNCTION {format.names} ```.

Comment: Are you sure that the function `format.names` has any bearing on the form of the punctuation mark after the `journal` field? I'd say one should begin with the line `journal emphasize "journal" output.check` in the function `article`. Specifically, it's the function `output.check` that would need to be modified to output a period instead of a comma.

Answer (score 2):

The correct function to change the comma after the journal name is `output.nonnull`:

```
FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ". " * write$ }             % <----- changed this from ", " to ". "
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}
```